# Apache rewrite rule forces download

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to port a PHP site developed by another coder (who is no longer around) and I'm having a problem with the Apache Rewrite rules which are prompting a file download on the target server.  I'm sure this is a simple problem, but I'm having some difficulty Googling an answer. I'm running on a (dedicated) Ubuntu Server with a standard installation of Apache and PHP5 and porting from shared a shared server where everything runs fine. No site files have been altered during the port.

The .htaccess file contains this code (only)

```
# Use PHP5 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
Options -Indexes FollowSymlinks


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^html/(.*)     /index.php?init=site\/$1\/$2\/$3\/$4\/$5\/$6\/$7\/$8\/$9

RewriteRule ^mykart$         /index.php?admin=true
RewriteRule ^mykart/$       /index.php?admin=true
RewriteRule ^mykart/(.*)$   /index.php?init=admin\/$1\/$2\/$3\/$4\/$5\/$6\/$7\/$8\/$9&admin=true
```

When I try to open the file http://www.mysite.com/html/#home the browser attempts to download the (index.php) file instead of displaying it, with the message

"You have chosen to Open
[dialog shows blank space here]

which is a: application/x-httpd-php 
 from....
"

I guess I must have missed something in either the PHP or Apache configuration, but what?

EDIT: To clarify, the server is running Apache2 and has several, functioning, PHP sites on it.  Furthermore if I delete the .htaccess file and run a simple phpinfo display page everything runs fine, so it's not the execution of PHP per see.

Comment: This is probably not the cause of your problem. But if you just have one group in your pattern, you could just have one match and thus only use $1 (besides the $0 for the whole match). And you don’t need to escape the `/`, neither in the pattern nor in the substitution part.

Comment: Oh, just another thought: I hope someone cannot gain admin privileges just by adding `admin=true` to the URL.

Comment: Heh. This is just one of a series of sites I've taken over and to say they are rife with issues is an understatement. Adding admin wouldn't work, but there's plenty of other holes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that the MIME type `application/x-httpd-php5` is not valid. I’ve tried it on my local machine and it caused the same behavior.

Have you tried `application/x-httpd-php` instead?

Comment: Thanks, yes that seems to solve it. Much appreciated, I have limited experience on Apache (much more familiar with PHP on the windows stack)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an Apache config issue, of course I could be wrong. Have you checked httpd.conf for the following lines:

```
# Add index.php to your DirectoryIndex line:
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

AddType text/html       php
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Browser attempted to download links from php website, instead of loading them.

It wasn't Php interpreter issue for me, it turned out to be misplaced .htaccess file. However, I didn't realized that disabling the htaccess file solved the issue for hours, due to browser cache.

So, **don't forget to clear your browser caches**! And restart Apache.